# How do I add avatar/profile pic in an app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app in a college project.  I am using firebase for the first time for authentication.  What is the best way of storing images for users profiles?

When the are on their profile page I want them to be able to add a picture (like whatsapp for example) but I'm unsure how this works with firebase

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Are you using google auth or asking user to upload profile pic after signing in with email and password  ? Based on that I can help

Comment: why you have to save user profile image? I mean if you are using firabase you can get imagepath from "user" class of firebase.

Comment: Hi MRX the user has logged in using email and password (haven't set up facebook login yet).  I then want their profile page to have a space for their photo above the textview for their name etc

Comment: H Ancee, thanks for your reply.  I am using firebase (but the first time I've used it).  I would like to have the option of the user having a profile photo.  They might not wish to use one of course

Comment: please add @ before user name so That dev can be notified :) Just saw your comment

Comment: cannot post my answer as its on hold

Comment: @MRX sorry - still learning the 'etiquette' ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase have a **Cloud Storage** too.

If you need to save a profile pic, you can add an image on firebase cloud storage and save image URL in your real-time database.

In this way, when you load user profiles you can retrieve information and load image by URL (you can use **Picasso** library to make it easy)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a profile for myself to test this, I'll add a photo and look into Picasso